# Forward Users to Custom Dashboard in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, permissions, user-roles

I'm trying to give the role 'subscriber' the ability to edit_post. 
While this is successful I cannot seem to direct users away from the default wordpress wp-admin page upon signing in.

Whenever I try a suggested solution users who login (with edit_post permission) get redirected to wp-admin page.

When they sign in no matter what I do wordpress forwards them to wp-admin showing the wordpress backend. (I do not want users to see this)

The reason why I want to do this is because I have a custom dashboard for them to use located at http://website.com/login/customdashboard/

I'd prefer this to be a function.

I've tried plugins with no success:
"Peter's Login Redirect" & also the "s2member (Login Welcome Page)"

I TRIED THE FOLLOWING FUNCTION WITH NO SUCCESS:

```
function soi_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user  ) {
    return ( is_array( $user->roles ) && in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) ? admin_url() : site_url();
} // end soi_login_redirect
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'soi_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

ANOTHER TRIED WITH NO SUCCESS:

```
function redirect_login_page(){
$page_viewed = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
 $login_page  = site_url();
 if( $page_viewed == "wp-login.php" && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
 wp_redirect($login_page);
 exit();
 }
}
add_action('init','redirect_login_page');
```

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but this seems like a [**Chameleon Question**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/185667). **One thing** is redirecting all `/wp-admin` URLs, and making this front-end deleting link work in that condition **is another**.

Comment: thanks - edited it back to keep integrity. :)

Comment: Cool, upvoted again to keep integrity ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect all `/wp-admin` address you can use:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirect_so_15396771' );

function redirect_so_15396771()
{   
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX )  
        return;

    // http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities
    if ( !current_user_can('delete_users') ) {
            wp_redirect( site_url( '/login/customdashboard/' ) );
            exit();
    }
}
```

If you need to filter this according to the current page, you can use the global `$pagenow`, which has the values `index.php`, `profile.php`, `tools.php`, etc.

Comment: Interesting - Is the delete_users permission the same as edit_posts? I'm just trying to understand it.

Comment: The above code seems to do what I want BUT it seems to be blocking my users ability to delete created posts. - any insights?

Comment: I'm allowing users to delete their posts via a delete link in the page itself tied to a function.

Comment: Well, that looks like a different Question. Because, blocking access to `/wp-admin` is one thing, blocking/enabling whatever custom code *(not published in the original Q)* you have is another. ::: Re: `delete_users`, check: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Comment: I've updated the Answer with an Ajax exception which may be interfering with any custom code.

Comment: Thanks - I've updated my question to include the code I'm using which may be causing conflict. Your update seems to be resulting in the same behavior. :(

Comment: agreed this is turning into a chameleon question - I will open up another one to address that specific need. You have seemed to solve my initial problem - thank you!